# Is there a way to do a textual search through all stored procedures for a table name?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've just inherited a database with a number of tables and stored procedures.  I use `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`.

One, or possibly more, stored procedures update a specific table.  I'd like to do a textual search through all the stored procedures to look for the procedure that updates the table.

If the raw SQL was in our code, I'd just `grep` the code base, but with stored procedures I'm not sure how to search through all the stored procedures.

I'd also like to rename a few things and do a find/replace throughout the stored procedures.

Is it possible to search and replace in stored procedures using `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`?

Comment: This is the free tool I use for searching for objects and text within procs, functions, etc.: [RedGate SQL Search 2](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)

Comment: @ShawnMelton, you should add this as an answer!

Comment: I like Idera's SQL Search tool which is part of the [SQL Admin Toolset](http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqladmintoolset).

Comment: @chollida just providing a link is not a proper etiquette for an answer on DBA.SE, hence just posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% reliable (could yield false positives, or miss things due to dynamic SQL etc):

```
SELECT s.name, p.name, m.definition
  FROM sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN sys.procedures AS p
  ON s.[schema_id] = p.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
  ON p.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
  WHERE LOWER(m.definition) LIKE N'%update%tablename%';
```

You can't *replace* directly (and I think you'd have a real hard time building a catch-all replace expression anyway, since T-SQL is not exactly rigidly structured), but you can script out the stored procedures you found, replace `CREATE` with `ALTER` and run that to apply changes.

I have written a much more expansive stored procedure that I use for searching across *all* objects in *all* databases, including even jobs, and I explain several caveats and show an even better way than `LOWER()` to handle case sensitivity (you may *want* the search to be case sensitive; the above assumes you don't care and want all matches regardless of case):

- https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/06/a-handy-search-procedure

Comment: Why LOWER(m.definition) ?

Comment: @aasim because some people have a case sensitive collation, where `update` <> `UPdaTe` <> `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (NAME NVARCHAR(MAX), CODE NVARCHAR(MAX));

DECLARE C CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT name FROM sys.procedures;
DECLARE @spname NVARCHAR(MAX), @sptext nvarchar(MAX);

OPEN C;
FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @spname
WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sptext = (select definition from sys.sql_modules
      where object_id=object_id(@spname) AND definition LIKE '%YourText%');
    IF @sptext IS NOT NULL
        INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (@spname, @sptext);

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @spname;
END

CLOSE C
DEALLOCATE C

SELECT * FROM #TempTable;

DROP TABLE #TempTable;
```

Comment: It took me some time to post my answer but the moment I was answering the question, it was still unanswered; I was just looking around my code snippets as I had this question before and that helped me. Yours is simpler, no temp tables or cursors.

Answer (score 0):

SSMS can show [where a table is used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/view-the-dependencies-of-a-table?view=sql-server-2017). Expand the hierarchy in Object Explorer until you see the table of interest. Right-click, "View Dependencies". A new window will appear listing those object (procedures, views etc.) that rely on the selected table. That list can be expanded to show second- and higher-order dependencies.